# Ambiguous formulation with respect to "minimal"

Tags: mathematics

To my understanding each of the following sentences

1. Let *x* be a minimal *foobar* containing *baz*.
2. Let *x* be a minimal *foobar* which contains *baz*.
3. Let *x* be a minimal *foobar* such that *x* contains *baz*.

can be interpreted either as "(minimal *foobar*) containing *baz*", i.e.

> x is minimal *foobar* and *baz* is in x

or  as "minimal (*foobar* containing *baz*)", i.e.

> x is *foobar* and *baz* is in x and there is no smaller *foobar* containing x

Would you consider one of these interpretations "standard" (in a mathematical context) and can you suggest concise alternative formulations that unambiguously refer to one of these?

Comment: If you want a mathematical interpretation (rather than an English language one) then you might want to try the Mathematics SE.

Comment: Your first parsing works for me. If you wanted to insist on minimal with respect to sets containing baz, you need to establish that idea separately, then define what minimum means in that regard.